# Google maps adding margin css property

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I've got google map whick looks like background of my page, and also I've got side menu with fixed width. I want to add margin to my map like menu's width. But for some reasons margin property doesn't work. I've tried to wrap my map with `div` and added margin to `div` but it also doesn't work. Any ideas?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/48/)

Here is a simple html structure

```
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="side-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>First</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by removing the `width: 100%;` and add `right: 150px;` instead of `margin-right: 150px;` to `#map_canvas` like this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pf86h27s/)

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 150px;
}
```

Comment: if i add right i will not be able to see part of map, it will be out of my screen

Comment: @user3127896 why did you accept this as an answer if it didn't work for you?